# What's the proper format for a book proposal that will be sent to multiple publishers?

Tags: publishing

I'm working on a book idea ( historical fiction with creative nonfiction pieces) and I want to create a proposal for it. I haven't done much research on publishers or that process yet, but I assume I'll be submitting my proposal to many different publishers for consideration. I want to create a book proposal that will satisfy most guidelines for submission.

I'm wondering things like:

- a good default font to type a proposal in.
- how much spacing should be between sentences.
- the overall format of a proposal; what information should be included?

So far I think I should include a quick intro of who I am and a few chapters of my work, but I'm a little lost about what else I should include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the Masterclass course on how to write a novel, thought by James Petterson, and his idea of an outline was different (and much better) than anything I saw online. He basically summarizes every single chapter of his books in a long paragraph for each. In the end, after reading the whole thing, the Publisher will have understood the entire plot. This is also a great idea for yourself as a writer too, because you will begin the "writing" part with all the pieces in place. All you have to do is flourish them with your scenes.

Comment: A summary is a part of many proposals, but this isn't, in general, an adequate answer to the question as given.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one answer for this:

Make your submission match the individual Publishers submissions guidelines.

They have them for a reason, and clearly state how submissions are to be formatted/compiled. And this means that yes, you will probably have to re-work it for each submissions.

If you don't want to do that, then don't expect it to be read or looked at.

Comment: I actually looked at a few different publishers before posting my question. The smaller ones that I looked at (and would actually give me the time of day) didn’t have specific guidelines which is why I’m asking the question.

Comment: Then ask them and not us.

Comment: You easily could’ve tailored your message to say there isn’t a default. The point is that I didn’t know if there was or not and so I’m asking for the standard. You don’t need to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting to a publisher that has their own guidelines, **you should follow those**, even if you are submitting many other places.  They provide them for a reason, and following directions is the easiest gatekeeper to pass on the route to publication.

In my experience, the following are the most common generic asks for a *modern* book proposal, which is entirely oriented around solving the question "how will we sell your book":

- **Hook:** Why would a reader buy this?
- **Audience**: Who would buy this?
- **Author's platform (formerly author bio):**  What are you bringing to the table that will help sell your book? (expertise, name-recognition, social media presence, networks, etc).
- **Comps (comparison books)**:  What similar books are currently doing well in sales?
- **Outline/Summary**: Some publishers/agents want a brief outline, others want a detailed, chapter-by-chapter summary, it's often best to include both.
- **Excerpt**: Some of the common guidelines are "the first 30 pages" or "the first 3 chapters".  It should be absolutely 100% free of errors and typos.

Generally, your proposal should be a double-spaced, unremarkable 12pt serif font like Times or Times New Roman.  I typically include a page header with my last name, the book title and the page number.  There are a number of good online and print resources with more detailed instructions, I would highly recommend finding and following one --*Writers' Market* generally includes one in each edition, for example.  Also be aware that many publishers/agents prefer to receive a query letter first, and a full proposal only on request.  (The query letter usually contains only the hook, platform and comps. It's a good idea to include some indication that you've specifically targeted the recipient, not just sent out a generic e-blast.)